# Use a helper in a layout

Tags: layout, magento-1, helper

I want to call a helper in the main layout of my website.

I added this within the  part of the layout :

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
    <label>About us</label>
    <url helper="myModule/getAboutUsUrl" />
    <title>About us</title> 
</action>
```

And defined my module in the /etc/config.xml this way :

```
<helpers>
    <myModule>
        <class>My_Module_Helper</class>
    </myModule>
</helpers>
```

I created my helper `My_Module_Helper_Data` at the root of `includes/src/`.

There is no error raised, but it seems that it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163730/magento-fatal-error-class-mage-wsalogger-helper-data-not-found-in-app-ma/25166093#25166093

Comment: I already did that. (sorry, the content of my "config.xml" file didn't appear on my post, I've just edited it). 
The helper loads, but it's like the return value of the method "getAboutUsUrl" isn't used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you putting helper file under include/src folder? It should be under your module Helper folder.

Have you enabled compilation mode? If yes then disable that first.

Make a helper class under your module folder and that position should be: `YourModuleNameSpace/ModuleName/Helper/Data.php`

Class name should be: `YourModuleNameSpace_ModuleName_Helper_Data`

Then write your function under this class.

Comment: That was my issue thank you ! Are the classes under include/src automatically generated ?

Comment: No, Once you will complete your extension then you can again enable compilation mode from the admin panel.So when you will enable it will automatically create a reference file of your helper class into include/src folder.

Answer (score 3):

You need create an module which define new helper types.

**Step1:** config.xml at `app/code/local/My/Module/` and it code should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <mymodule>
                <class>My_Module_Helper</class>
            <mymodule>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Step2:** create Data.php at `app/code/local/My/Module/Helper/`

```
class My_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getAboutUsUrl()
    {
        //you code
    }
}
```

**Step3:** create My_Module.xml at `app/etc/modules/` and code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step4:** Disable Compiler and clear cache from admin and check y_Module in *admin > system > Configuration > .. > Advance*

**Step5:** enable compiler again

**Step6:** add new link by add below code at layout file at local.xml at `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_template/layout/` and put this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" /></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="mymodule">
                <label>About us</label>
                <url helper="mymodule/getAboutUsUrl" />
                <title>About us</title> 
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```