# Get rewritten URL for custom link in customer account dashboard

Tags: url-rewrite, frontend, customer-account, dashboard, geturl

To my customer account dashboard (and index) I want to add a custom (direct) link to a product category. This product category is only visible to logged in customers, that's why I want to have it here, too (not just in the basic store category view /listing)

I managed to list the link with adding

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
    <name>downloads_category</name>
    <url>catalog/category/view/id/93</url>
    <label>Downloads Category</label>
</action>
```

to the `<customer_account>` block in my `customer.xml` file.
But I struggle on getting the rewritten URL (downloads.html, as set in rewrite management). The rewrite-URL works fine in the frontend.

Using `downloads.html` as the `<url></url>` parameter will end up adding a link to `/.../downloads.html/` (with that unwanted trailing slash).

**Edit**: I'm running Magento CE 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the rewritten URL as `href` with using the `urlParams` as follows:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
    <name>downloads-category</name>
    <url>catalog/category/view/id/101</url>
    <label>Downloads</label>
    <urlParams>
         <_direct>downloads.html</_direct>
    </urlParams>
</action>
```

It's not *dynamic* but at least it is not a non-SEF-URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper in your layout to generate the URL.
Take a look at this subject, it may help you : [Use a helper in a layout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35929/use-a-helper-in-a-layout)

Comment: So du you suggest that there's no "native" way to do that in magento?

Comment: If by native way you mean pure XML no, but this solution don't need any override or third extension, so this is kinf of native way ;)